# Know Your Site Monday: Who are the tag masters?

Tags: discussion, trivia

Welcome to 'Know Your Site', an every Monday Worldbuilding trivia feature where I use the Stack Exchange Data Explorer and maybe some python parsing to find out interesting things about the site.

I will post a question on Monday, and people have until Thursday at noon to guess the answer! To be clear, using the Data Explorer to get the answer is cheating. If you use that to find the answer, feel good about your inherent superiority, but don't post it! Also, absolutely do not look at my Data Explorer profile, because that is definitely cheating.

After three consecutive weeks of having my question answered in about 30 minutes, you guys have forced me to take extreme measures. For this week's question, **Who is the highest reputation user whose highest tag score is a a certain tag?**

Difficultly worded question, so here are some examples. Who is the highest reputation user that has [reality-check](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reality-check) as their highest tag?  How about for [science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based)? Looking at the list in order of reputation:

```
Name          Reality Check      Science Based
Cort Ammon             2526               1489
Thucydides             1592               1494
JDlugosz               1417               1675
Separatrix             1953               1236
Tim B                  1028               1906
Will                   1724               1897
HDE 226868              845               1402
kingledion             1841               2340
```

Cort Ammon has more rep in [reality-check](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reality-check) than any other tag, and is the highest rep user for which this is true, so Cort Ammon is the answer for [reality-check](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reality-check). JDlugosz, Tim B, Will, HDE 226868 and kingledion all have more [science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based) than any other tag; of these, JDlugosz has the highest rep, so he is the answer for [science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based), even though other users have a higher score for that tag. Make sense?

For these other tags, which user who has their highest tag score in each tag has the most overall reputation?

- [alternate-history](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternate-history)
- [biology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biology)
- [climate](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climate)
- [creature-design](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creature-design)
- [economy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economy)
- [evolution](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evolution)
- [geography](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geography)
- [government](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/government)
- [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science)
- [humans](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humans)
- [language](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language)
- [magic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic)
- [physics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics)
- [planets](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planets)
- [politics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/politics)
- [religion](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/religion)
- [science-fiction](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction)
- [society](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/society)
- [space](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space)
- [space-travel](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-travel)
- [technology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology)
- [warfare](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warfare)
- [weapons](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons)
- [worldbuilding-process](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/worldbuilding-process)
- [xenobiology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xenobiology)

#### Important limitations

- Ignore [science-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-based) and [reality-check](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reality-check). As far as I can tell, *every* user has one of those two a their top tag.
- The user must have at least 10 not-closed answers in a certain tag to count. Thus, if you have 581 score from one post in computers, [for example](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/31388/how-would-facebook-sysadmins-prevent-the-summoning-of-cthulhu/31419#31419), you don't count.  I made this limit because one-off answers with 100+ votes tend to skew things oddly.
- Please post partial answers; you probably need it on this one :)

Comment: Why would we call them the "tag master", instead of saying whoever has the highest tag score for a given tag is a "tag master".

Comment: @PyRulez If you have a better suggestion, feel free to edit it in :)

Comment: Well, its kind of too late now, since people have already started answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Secespitus's answer is good, but here are the corrections to his answer.

- [evolution](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evolution) -> [March Ho](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/4790/march-ho?tab=tags)
- [government](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/government) -> [Shadow1024](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/25459/shadow1024?tab=tags)
- [humans](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humans) -> [GaryWalker](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/7325/gary-walker?tab=tags)
- [physics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics) -> [2012rcampion](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3407/2012rcampion?tab=tags)
- [space-travel](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-travel) -> [JBH](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/40609/jbh?tab=tags)
- [weapons](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons) -> [Samuel](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3202/samuel?tab=tags)
- [xenobiology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xenobiology) -> [Slarty](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/42450/slarty?tab=tags)

Maybe we'll go for a little bit easier next time....

Answer (score 3):

- [alternate-history](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternate-history) -> [AlexP](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/29552/alexp)
- [biology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biology) -> [JDługosz](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/885/jd%c5%82ugosz)
- [climate](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/climate) -> [Vincent](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/147/vincent)
- [creature-design](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/creature-design) -> [TrEs-2b](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11049/tres-2b)
- [economy](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/economy) -> [Brythan](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2113/brythan)
- [evolution](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evolution) -> [rek](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/25189/rek) (The highest non-excluded tag is [water](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water), but the user has less than 10 water answers; ... upon further inspection he also only has 7 answers and 6 questions, so this is wrong too...)
- [geography](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geography) -> [Mikey](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/3276/mikey)
- [government](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/government) -> [John Robinson](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/13430/john-robinson) (wrong; too few answers)
- [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science) -> [Jim2B](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/7886/jim2b)
- [humans](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humans) -> [Thorsten S.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/7089/thorsten-s)
- [language](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) -> [Lostinfrance](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/9207/lostinfrance)
- [magic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic) -> [Cort Ammon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2252/cort-ammon)
- [physics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics) -> [JBH](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/40609/jbh)
- [planets](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planets) -> [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868)
- [politics](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/politics) -> [Avernium](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11306/avernium)
- [religion](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/religion) -> [Pedro Gabriel](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/20681/pedro-gabriel)
- [science-fiction](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction) -> [ZioByte](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/38942/ziobyte)
- [society](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/society) -> [o.m.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/6402/o-m)
- [space](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space) -> [Michael Kjörling](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/29/michael-kj%c3%b6rling)
- [space-travel](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-travel) -> [Catgut](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/16883/catgut) (wrong; too few answers)
- [technology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology) -> [Separatrix](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/16295/separatrix)
- [warfare](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warfare) -> [Thucydides](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/8572/thucydides)
- [weapons](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapons) -> [Aify](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/6453/aify)
- [worldbuilding-process](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/worldbuilding-process) -> [rumguff](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/11859/rumguff)
- [xenobiology](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xenobiology) -> [Z.Schroeder](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/21870/z-schroeder)

Comment: @kingledion That "10 post minimum" requirement is horrible...

Comment: I just wanted the question to make it until tomorrow...

Comment: @kingledion We'll see about that :D

Comment: Current score card is 1 blank, 2 known wrong (as stated in parenthesis) and  six more still wrong.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I am the master of the Worldbuilding-process tag.

Comment: Actually...I just realized I haven't cleaned it up in a while...time to go delete some tags.

Comment: @James Your highest tag is "society", therefore you have to fight in the "society" group - you can't even be considered for worldbuilding-process

Comment: I object! Mainly because I am not the winner in society.

Answer (score 1):

for space-travel > [MolbOrg](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/20315/molborg)